# java -cp on Windows problem

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath, classnotfoundexception

Can someone please tell me why this java command in a .bat file won't run my java program on WinXP? I have all my jar files in a folder called lib and my class files in a package folder mypackage.

```
java -cp ".;.\lib\poi-3.7-20101029.jar;.\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;..." mypackage.MyClassWithMain
```

I have tried all sorts of things to no avail. I get a ClassNotFound error as soon as the program attempts to use some of the classes in the jar files. So, I think there's something wrong with my -cp option. It does find my main().

I want to give this program to someone who doesn't know a thing about computers, so I want them to be able to double-click the .bat file and go.

I wrote everything on a mac without much problem.

I bet the moderator is going to slap me upside the head for this question, but I did search extensively for an answer to this.

Thanks you!
John

Sorry, I should have put in the entire command line:

java -cp ".;.\libs\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;.\libs\poi-3.7-20101029.jar;.\libs\poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar;.\libs\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar;.\libs\resolver.jar;.\libs\xbean.jar;.\libs\xbean_xpath.jar;.\libs\xmlbeans-qname.jar;.\libs\xmlpublic.jar" excelsifter.ExcelSifterController

This is all on one line. I tried / instead of \, but that didn't seem to work. Everything I could find on this indicates that for windows you have to use the backslash.
All the dependencies are here, as far as I know. At least my mac doesn't complain when I use essentially the same command.

My directory containing my .bat file contains the excelsifter package (a folder called excelsifter) and the folder libs with all the jar files in it.
Thanks, John

Comment: can you show the dir structure

Comment: Have you tried `/` instead of `\\`?  Are you sure the files are in the relative path, i.e. do you change the directory correctly?

Comment: could you add information on which classes are not found?  Which jar file are they coming from?  Are you sure that that jar file is being built?

Comment: Please post the full exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Your starting string looks ok to me, try to check if there are other dependencies in the libraries you use as @Said mentioned. The best way is to search for class your java cannot find, probably you'll find it declaration in some other library you didn't included in your classpath.

Comment: It may well be that the library not included in the classpath does not need to be on the classpath in one machine because it's inside the JDK or JRE directory (`jre/lib/ext` maybe?) on that machine.

Comment: Thanks, that was it... I didn't include a jar file I needed in my classpath.